# Puppeteer: is it possible to set the uniqueness of the selector choice?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

There is a structure as follows:

```html
<div class="masterselector">
   <div class="selector_what_me_need selector01 selector02"><div>not need value</div></div>
   <div class="selector_what_me_need"><div>need value</div></div>
</div>
```

How can I select text "need value" only the second in `div` element with class `selector_what_me_need`?

upd.
Solution (i have many this block):

```html
await page.$$eval('.masterselector .selector_what_me_need:not(.selector01):not(.selector02) div', el => el.map(e => e.textContent));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to select it here are some :

```
.selector_what_me_need:not(.selector01)
```

```
div:not(.selector01):not(.masterselector)
```

```
div[class$=need]
```

Code :

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const html = `
    <div class="masterselector">
    <div class="selector_what_me_need selector01 selector02">not need value</div>
    <div class="selector_what_me_need">need value</div>
    </div>
`;


let browser;
(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    // const page = await browser.newPage();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    await page.setContent(html);

    //let selector = ".selector_what_me_need:not(.selector01)";
    //let selector = "div:not(.selector01):not(.masterselector)";
    let selector = "div[class$=need]";  // means ends with
    let text = await page.$eval(selector, el => el.textContent);     
    console.log(text);

    await browser.close();

})().catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake, i edit my post.

Comment: @issikkul removed the ones that wont work with updated quesiton, the others all work.